# My new created block for footer links will not show up in frontend

Tags: magento2.3, footer

I work in Magento 2.3.

I removed the general footer links by

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
```

But now i add a new block and widget but it wont show up.

I tried the next YouTube link but no result

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrzSjBNqrho&list=PLtaXuX0nEZk9eL59JGE3ny-_GAU-z5X5D&index=22

Where is my mistake?

Regards Gerwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**create static block**

```
Identifier - my_custom_footer
```

**add code in your theme default.xml**

```
   <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer-custom-link" after="-">
                     <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">my_custom_footer</argument>
                     </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>    
        </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: This is default.xml now

Comment: Where can i add this? At the end of the file default?

Comment: paste  inside body tag

Comment: I am a newby in magento. Can you tell me exactly where to paste?

Comment: open default.xml and paste code before </body> tag

Comment: do you understand?

Comment: Thanks, i can add those. Only the colour of the letters is blue. Can i change that?

Comment: yes you can change

Comment: Ok thanks! if i make a new one in the footer where can i manage the content?

Comment: create static block (for example- --- my_custom_footer_new) and define in xml => for example <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer-custom-new" after="-">
                     <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">my_custom_footer_new</argument>
                     </arguments>
                </block>

Comment: I think you misunderstand..... Can i also add a printscreen here to explain what i mean? I made a new subject in the footer and content in a page but cannot see it.

Comment: sorry i don't  understand what you exactly asking @Lapparts Where are you from?

Comment: I am from holland. I mean there are 5 subjects in the footer now. I made a new subject, but cannot link the content and url with it.

Comment: @Lapparts please send me your code

Comment: Which code Savan? Can i add here a printscreen?

Comment: @Lapparts  yes please add

Comment: Sorry, i dont see how to do?

Comment: Can you help me explain how to add content in a footerlink and link it together?

Answer (score 0):

**step 1 create static block**

```
Find create block Identifier name
```

**step 2  This code add in your theme in default.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
    <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content" >
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="(block identifier name) ">
                    <arguments>
                            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer1(block identifier name)</argument>
                    </arguments>
            </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <container name="cms_footer_links_container" label="CMS Footer Links" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="links" before="footer_links" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="privacy-policy-link">
                <arguments>

Comment: Where can i add this code you mentioned?

Comment: you are add custom theme than this code  add in app/design/frontend/ <your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml